# Post response from postman call to Azure logic app http url throws request content cannot be deserialized

Tags: postman, azure-logic-apps

Making a post call with a payload in body from postman to the HTTP url from Azure logic app. I am trying to pass a variable dynamically to the logic app to execute a query. I defined schema in the request body schema section in logic app. Also a payload in the postman body. I am **receiving an error:**
"error": {
"code": "InvalidRequestContent",
"message": "The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: a. Path 'AccountId', line 2, position 18.'."

**Request Body JSON Schema in logic app-**

```
{
    "kind": "Http",
    "inputs": {
        "schema": {
            "properties": {
                "AccountId": {
                    "type": "String"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

**Postman payload:**

```
{
    "AccountId": [{{MemberId}}]
}
```

Content type is defined under header section to application/json
The workflow in the logic app is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbiJu.jpg)

Need to pass the memberid from postman to AccountId in Azure logic app. The query in logic app uses AccountId to execute the query

Comment: Where'd you define that payload from?  It's not proper JSON.  Are you the definer of the payload or is that being sourced from elsewhere?

Comment: Postman payload is not correct. As per the json schema 'AccountId' is string property but in postman input you are sending it as array. Try with below postman input: {
    "AccountId": "MemberId"
}

Comment: @Skin Payload is defined by me. I am trying to send the memberID generated in a previous step.

Comment: @PankajMore Thank you, I changed the input to {"AccountId":"{{MemberID}}" before I saw your reply here :). MemberID is a global variable which holds the memberID generated in a previous step.

Comment: @Shar Can you please add your answer? So that it will be helpful for other community members

Comment: Sure. the following is the body I used in the postman call
{
    "AccountId": "{{MemberId}}"
}
And this worked